# How to shallow render in react 18?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs

My `Item` component accepts a literal object with some details and a function to be triggered with a button. It looks great for now but I'd like to perform some rendering tests to check that all components are in the document plus testing a button that takes the user back to the shop page and a button that fires the function I mentioned before.

As for 2023, `Enzyme` version is up to 16 which makes `shallow(/*a component*/)` impossible because I'm not able to install the adapter `npm install enzyme-adapter-react-16 --save dev` which can't resolve a dependency. I also tried to `import { ShallowRenderer } from "react-dom/test-utils"` but when I tried to create a renderer `const renderer = new ShallowRenderer()` I got a `ShallowRenderer is not a constructor` all of that was based on [Shallow Renderer](https://hy.reactjs.org/docs/shallow-renderer.html) old documentation. I know, it wasn't likely to work but the idea was to make it work to understand why later.

It actually all started with the following test where `render` is imported from `@testing-library/react` which is the orthodox way. However, Jest complain with `Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'React__namespace.useContext(...)' as it is null.]`. In all honestly I don't have a clue what that error means and whether shallow rendering is the way to go to test my component.

Here's my code

item.js

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";

const Item = ({info},{addCart}) => {

  return(
    <>
      <button data-testid='link'><Link to="/">X</Link></button>
      <img data-testid='pic' src={info.pic} alt={info.title}></img>
      <h1 data-testid='title'>{info.title}</h1>
      <p data-testid='description'>{info.description}</p>
      <button data-testid='add-item' onClick={()=>{addCart({info})}}>Add</button>
    </>
  )
};

export default Item;
```

item.test.js

```
import React from "react";
import { render, cleanup,screen} from "@testing-library/react";
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import Item from "./item";

afterEach(cleanup);
const details = {pic: `a pic`, title:`a title`, description:`a description`}
const func =jest.fn(); 

test(`Content renders`,()=>{
  render(<Item info={details} addCart={func}/>);
  expect(screen.getByRole('button', {name: 'X'})).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Does anyone know where to find up to date documentation about this?

Please note that my goal is to render `Item` with the `details` object literal and the `funct` function mock in `item.test.js`

Again, should I shallow render the component? Should I write the test in another way?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Enzyme is no longer supported as a testing library for the latest versions of React and the preferred testing library is react-testing-library.

As a general rule, react testing library discourages using mocks (shallow rendering) according to its [guiding principles](https://testing-library.com/docs/guiding-principles/).

There is an answer on the [FAQ](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/faq) for react testing library that addresses shallow rendering by using [Jest mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks).  They give some [examples](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-transition-group/#shallow) of how you could do that if you follow some of the links.

I'm not sure this will work, but off the top of my head, this is how I would write a test for the Item component "Add" button functionality:

```js
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react"
import Item from "./item"
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'

describe("Item Component", () => {
  test("Button calls addCart function with items", () => {
    const addCartMock= jest.fn()
    const details = {pic: `a pic`, title:`a title`, description:`a description`}
    render(<Item info={details} addCart={addCartMock}/>);

    userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button", {name: "Add"}))

    expect(addCartMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(details)
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks @ckesplin! I've just taken your code and test it but I get the same rendering problem. However, your approach to test the click event is better than my so you contributing to my code anyway. Definitely, it's worth reading the docs you suggest, I'll take them a look to get some clues.